# Implementing a dynamic FlatCollection<T>

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, collections

I need to either create, or use an existing .NET FW FlatCollection.
What I mean by a FlatCollection is, a Collection that, when an element is inserted through the Add method/function, will check the element, and if such element is an IEnumerable, will take all the elements from such IEnumerable and add them to the collection. (This behavior only applies to a root IEnumerable, however, applying it recursively to sub-IEnumerables could also be good, albeit harder). The trick is, that this FlatCollection, being an indexed collection, needs to preserve the order of its elements.

Say a user adds an IEnumerable of 3 elements to the Collection, and at some point afterwards adds a new element to that collection being referenced; the FlatCollection needs to notice that the list has changed size, and update its internal collection to reflect the new element, maintaining the ordering. So if for example, a user adds an Empty collection between two single elements, and then populates the collection with 3 elements, the two single elements will still be before and after the newly added 3 elements.

I could, of course, implement this myself by inheriting from collection and defining all of this behavior, but it is tricky as you need to keep a count of the number of items in the added IEnumerable (IEnumerable does not have a count), and its starting index in the collection. The first thing that came to mind was to use a linked list as the internal collection since you will be resizing a lot, but I am not sure what would be best.

However, if there is an easier way to do this rather than implementing the whole thing from scratch I.E. using existing .NET FrameWork elements I would like to know! As this is the purpose of my question.

To summarize:
I am looking for the best performing, and easiest way to implement a FlatCollection, possibly using .NET FW elements.

Comment: What interfaces do you need to implement? If you only need `IEnumerable<T>`, I'd just keep the *original* collections, and iterate over them lazily.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is for a custom CompositeCollection implementation I am writing for Windows Phone 8. So, whatever interface methods are called by an ItemsControl's ItemsSource to populate the items of such ItemsControl are the ones I need.

Comment: @JonSkeet At first I thought it only used the Enumerator since the ItemsSource is of type IEnumerable, however, after writing a CompositeEnumerator (http://1drv.ms/P9mzRx) that enumerates through a Lazy Collection in this manner, I noticed it doesn't just use the methods in IEnumerable. The .NET CompositeCollection class uses IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, INotifyCollectionChanged, so I would need to use the generic version of these.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera You should really think of this as tree and not a collection. I'm sure it will make tackling this problem easier.

Comment: @Euphoric that definitely sounds like a good approach, provided this tree structure exposes the necessary interface elements.
I don't know if you saw, but I need this FlatCollection to implement IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, and INotifyCollectionChanged (to propagate changes to the UI).
I am not sure if implementing these violates the principles of such a tree structure.

Comment: There is one glaring issue that stands out here to me. If you add a collection in as one of the items in this flat collection, and then later modify that collection, the flat collection will have no clue. Thus, even if INotifyPropertyChanged was implemented, FlatCollection would have no clue that the underlying collection was modified (as no methods of its own were called) without being itself notified.

Comment: @TravisJ, that is part of the problem :)
See the second paragraph of my question.
The easiest solution, really, would be to implement it as a lazy collection of sorts.
The problem is, however, as I mentioned to Jon Skeet, that I believe the rest of the collection methods (this[int index], remove, removeat, contains, indexof, count...) have to return a Flat "view" of the collection, rather than the lazy collections themselves, because the ItemsControl does not just use the enumerator of its ItemsSource IEnumerable.

Comment: Maybe just type constrain it to FlatCollection<T> : where T : INotifyCollectionChanged? and listen to those events from within the FlatCollection<T> for each collection added?
This seems really expensive though, 1. listening to all those CollectionChangedEvents, and 2. recreating the list (or adding nodes if it is a linked list) for every time the collection is changed.

Comment: I just went through the .NET FW CompositeCollection class, all legal, of course, and noticed that the way they do it is by implementing ICollectionViewFactory ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionviewfactory(v=vs.95).aspx ). This is probably what I need, and what WPF/SL will use, in XAML, to get the items of the CompositeCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some kind of tree structure. Each "collection" is node, each node can have arbitrary number of children and values are leaves. By going In-order through just leaves, you create the "flat" collection you want. It also works recursively so you can ask any node and it will give you correct "flat sub-collection".

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142.aspx) may just do all you need if you have your "flat collection" as simple `List<IEnumerable<T>>`.

```
  List<IEnumerable<MyItemType>> listOfEnumerables = new ...
  IEnumerable<List<MyItemType>> flattened =
                listOfEnumerables.Select(x => x);
```

You may also wrap that call in a class if you want to hide details:

```
 class FlatCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
 {
    List<IEnumerable<T>> list = new ...

    public Add(T item) { list.Add(Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1);}
    public Add(IEnumerable<T> item) { list.Add(item);}

    // use Enumerable.SelectMany to imeplent IEnumerable
  }
```

Comment: You can't set the first item in this collection though, as `IEnumerable` doesn't provide any operations for mutation.

Comment: Would this support the indexed expansion of previously added IEnumerables?
IF a user changes an IEnumerable that was previously added, will the change propagate to the FlatCollection<T>?

Comment: @Servy not sure what you mean "You can't set the first item"... I don't see requirement for collection itself to add new elements into existing `IEnumerable` (like listOfEnumerables[3].Add(newItem)`).

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera - yes... if you add real enumerable and not a copy - i.e.  adding `myEnumerable.ToList()` will not work...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1) returns an IEnumerable<T>. I don't understand how adding all the items in this enumerable to the list would support the indexed expansion I spoke of, could you clarify? ( I'm also assuming you meant to use list.AddRange not list.Add )
Thanks!

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera - I thought that you just need `IEnumerable` which can be easily done with `SelectMany` to flatten collection of enumerables... - clearly not enough for your case. On my suggestion - notice that `list` is collection of `IEnumerable<T>`, not flattened list - so updating inserted enumerable will be visible during iteration over `SelectMany` results. This is not going to work for you as you need to listen and re-fire change events as far as I understand.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah, this wouldn't work because of other constraints on my design (the need to be able to "update" the FlatCollection<T> when its referenced lists are updated.
I'm resorting to writing a custom tree of sorts, where it would be easier to add and remove items, etc. and update the list by subscribing to CollectionChangedEvents.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera - Why do you think my suggestion does not support update btw? It does not allow listening for changes (you'd have to require `INotifyPropertyChange` or some similar interface too from elements)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I understand that :)
But in the scenario where I would need to support updates, the Tree would be simpler to write. Wouldn't need to resize an array, or iterate through many elements in a linked list, etc.